# Create ASP.NET Webforms application on ASP.NET Core website

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Asp.Net Core web site targeting NET Framework 4.6.1 on IIS.

On that domain, I would like to have a subdomain with Web Forms web services, so I created a web application in IIS, with a different application pool.

www.example.com: asp.net core web site with no managed code in the application pool
www.example.com/soap : asp.net webforms with manage code in the application pool.

For some reason, I am getting an error 502.5, the application process failed to start. The URL is picked up by the asp.net core engine, before it can go to the separate web application in the sub directory.

what is needed to get this working?

Comment: Did you make the Web Forms app a virtual application of the ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: Yep, but core takes the routing. So I need to do something in IIS that takes the URL before it goes to core.
I found I can do soap.example.com, but I'd rather have the url described in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 4.5 throws 502.5 as a virtual application in Azure Web App under a ASP.NET Core 2.0 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103786/asp-net-4-5-throws-502-5-as-a-virtual-application-in-azure-web-app-under-a-asp-n)